# Distinguishing empty subroutines from subroutines with at least some minimal code

Tags: perl

Is it possible in a way that doesn't involve deparsing the subroutine in question via `B::Deparse` or whatever back into its source form? The task at hand is to know whether a particular subroutine reference points NOT to a predeclared one w/o an actual body (like `package Foo;sub x :ATTR(...); ... sub x { ... }`), when an attribute (via `Attribute::Handlers`) is applied to it. At first I thought the `$code` parameter will be undefined in such case, but as it turned out it is not. While deparsing can be used for this task, as such subroutines return a mere `';'` as their decompiled code via `B::Deparse`, using it for large functions has its considerations, as well as dependency on this output across all versions of Perl, used modules, etc, etc. Not pretty.

Comment: What is the use case for wanting to do this?

Comment: My internal object library generates accessors for properties based on data supplied via an attribute applied to a subroutine. The name of the subroutine is the name of the property, while it will be transformed into a sub that handles getting and setting the property. The library allows to supply custom getters and setters, of course. The usual case is to specify either one in a named parameter, and take the code for the other from the sub's body. But for that to work, I have to distinguish between a sub w/ no body and a regular sub, so in the first case I could generate an implicit accessor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I've found a solution w/o deparsing or size tests. Using the B module, I can query

```
my $cv=B::svref_2object($code);
undef $code if ref $cv->START eq 'B::NULL';
```

where `if ref $cv->START eq 'B::NULL'` in my, admittedly limited testing, is true *only and only* if a sub was *only* predeclared. It even filters out subs with no statements like `sub x{}`, exactly as I desire, unlike the former solution. My only gripe with this are possible differences across different Perl versions, but I couldn't find such info yet; I'm sticking to my current version anyway for the most part.

I've found it by a blind guess, I got pointed in the right direction by a book named "Perl Hacks: Tips & Tools for Programming, Debugging, and Surviving" by Chromatic, Damian Conway and Curtis Poe ([link](https://books.google.ru/books?id=CLKbAgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA204&ots=0QhsjAuvIB&dq=perl%20get%20the%20count%20of%20a%20subroutine%20opcodes&hl=ru&pg=PA201#v=onepage&q=perl%20get%20the%20count%20of%20a%20subroutine%20opcodes&f=false%20)). It described how to find the *largest* subroutine in a module. So I hoped to rewrite the code to just get the size of a given subroutine, but the code was too heavy to be used in the project, including another CPAN module dependency. So I looked for another option, fiddled with CPAN `B::TerseSize` modules, until I found out they pretty much all use `B` in one way or another to do their thing. But looking at the documentation of the `B` module was a chore. Long story short, I just guessed `START` is the thing I'm looking for in the end, after furious printing of return values of various `CV` methods.